# Check jQuery version and load and use later version if needed

Tags: jquery, portlet

I am using jQuery in a portal environment. The portal header files are loading jQuery 1.4.2 and there are other portlets using that version of jQuery. However, I recently discovered a bug that was fixed in jQuery 1.4.3, so I want to use that version for my portlet.

I know how to detect the jQuery version. But, I am not sure how to dynamically load the later version of jQuery, alias it for use in my portlet and then change it back to the older version so other portlets that are loaded later on the same page as my portlet are unaffected.

I have tried several different things are have not been successful in getting it work. Basically, what I want to do is load jQuery 1.4.3 dynamically and alias it to the jQuery variable so all of the code in my portlet uses 1.4.3, then at the end of my portlet, alias the jQuery variable back to 1.4.2 so any following portlets use that version.

Can this be done? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple versions in a page is a *very bad idea*, work around the bug, don't try to include multiple versions on a single page.

For starters, you'll overwrite the jQuery object initially (unless you modify jQuery core) and lose any plugins that were defined.

Comment: +1 This has extremely undesirable consequences. I did this once on accident and I couldn't determine which jQuery object I had loaded, so at different times I was working on a different jQuery objects.  As @Nick stated, this can and **will** destroy plugins.

Comment: I can appreciate your statement. Unfortunately, the bug is in jQuery itself, so it is difficult to work around it in my own code. Any other thoughts on what I could do without using two versions of jQuery?

Comment: I worked around it using the instructions in the ticket, but it feels very icky to modify jQuery core code.